# How to synchronize my PGP key server with another server?

Tags: synchronization, gnupg, pgp

Can know how to sync my PGP key server with another server? So I had all the keys from another server on my own SKS OpenPGP Public Key Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenPGP key servers can synchronize with each other. The protocol which is used most is SKS, implemented by the [SKS key server](https://bitbucket.org/skskeyserver/sks-keyserver/wiki/Home) software and [hockeypuck](http://hockeypuck.github.io/). Ask other key server operators if they'd like to synchronize with your server and then configure your key server software appropriately. How to do so depends on the software and can be read in its manual, mostly it boils down to putting their URIs in some configuration file (which they also have to do with yours).

More details on how the synchronization works and how to find peers can be found in an excellent [**article on keysigning.org on setting up your own key server**](http://www.keysigning.org/sks/) (scroll down to *Set Up Peer Communications*).